# Load User Control dynamically in C# and assign the Public properties of that control

Tags: c#, dynamic-usercontrols

I want to load the user controls dynamically on my page. I can load the control dynamically with the help of following code:

```
UserControl ctrl =(UserControl) Page.LoadControl(ControlPath);
dvUserControls.Controls.Clear();
dvUserControls.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

`dvUserControls` is just a div with `runat = "server"`

My problem is that I have to assign the values to the public properties of the controls also .I can't register my control to the aspx page.

Please advise.

Thanks
Rohit

Comment: Instead of casting it to a UserControl type, try to cast it in the type of your control like:
YOURCONTROL ctrl = (YOURCONTROL)Page.LoadControl(path);

Comment: YOURCONTROL is not available in my webpage how to cast it

Comment: YOURCONTROL means the name of your control, what is the name of your .ascx control, its name must be replaced in place of YOURCONTROL

Comment: Hi Imran ..yes that I know YOURCONTROL meanse my user comtrol's name but when I am typing the name of my control it is not available on my page where I am adding it dynamically

Comment: have you added the namespace of your control on top of page by the keyword 'using'?

Answer (score 0):

it the type of usercontrol is not available(you say which is your case) you can (and have to) use reflection

Comment: Is there any other way of accessing properties of control other thatn reflection?

Comment: yes you can use dynamic variable. other then that there is no solution because type is not available

Answer (score 0):

This is how is it working with me:

```
MyListControl myListControl = (MyListControl)page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MyListControl.ascx");
myListControl.SourceId = 1;
//Further Processing
```

on top of my page, i have:

```
using MyProject.UI.Controls;
```